# Feature matching using opensurf

Tags: surf

I am working on a project in which I need to match surf features in a same image , please help me in how can i match surf features in a same image using opensurf library .

Answer (score 1):

This may be accomplished by using the getMatches function found in the OpenSURF library (ipoint.cpp). You typically have to feed in the relevant interest points from the two images in question.

Hope this helps!

Comment: also, see http://amitsarangi.wordpress.com/tag/opensurf/ to get a brief overview of how matching is used.